# store time in django like 12:30 am/pm python/django

Tags: python, django

```
this is model:
class AgencyDetail(models.Model):
    from_time = models.TimeField()
    to_time = models.TimeField()
```

template:

```
<label>From Time:</label>

<select name="state3" class="fromtime">
                          {% for x in a %}
                                <option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
                           {% endfor %
</select><br/>



<label>To Time:</label>
<select name="state4" class="totime">

                          {% for x in a %}
                                <option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
                           {% endfor %}
              </select><br/><br/>


this my views:

def registration(request, *args, **kwargs):
    a=['%s:%s%s' % (h, m, ap) for ap in ('am', 'pm') for h in ([12] + range(1,12)) for m in ('00', '30')]
    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.POST
        regis_form = AgencyDetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if regis_form.is_valid():
            agency_data = regis_form.save(commit = False)
            agency_data.from_time=request.POST['state3']
            agency_data.to_time=request.POST['state4']
            agency_data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/car_detail/')

    else:
        regis_form = AgencyDetailForm()
    state_data = State.objects.all()
    return render(request,"registration.html", {'regis_form': regis_form,'state_data':state_data,'a':a})
```

i am select time from drop down like 12:30 am and save selected time into db as it is.
but it save only 12:30:00 it does not include am/pm. i am using PostgreSQL.

```
what i do?
```

Comment: I would save an accurate representation of time as a datetime data type and then *display* as am/pm if that's what you want.

Comment: Also there is not enough information here. Please show the contents of the request, your models and mention the database you're using.